# Magnific popup closes on content click after replacing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

I am using **Magnific Popup version 0.8.9.**

I am loading content into it via Ajax, and I use a callback for `ajaxContentAdded`. This callback sets up an event handler for submitting a form that was loaded into the popup, like so:

```
$('.add-item-btn').magnificPopup({ 
    type: 'ajax',
    closeOnContentClick: false,
    callbacks: {
        ajaxContentAdded: HandleItemFormSubmit
    }
});
```

This works fine, the form submit is handled correctly. The event handler function posts it to the server, which (in case of errors) returns the entire form including error messages.
For this purpose I let it replace the popup's content with the returned form, and setup the submit handler again.

```
function HandleItemFormSubmit()
{
    var popup = this;
    // Submit form using ajax
    $('form.item-form').submit(function()
    {
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');

        $.post(url, data, function(resp)
        {
            if (resp == 'OK')
            {
                // All good, close up
                popup.close();  
            }
            else
            {
                // Show HTML from response (with errors)
                popup.closeOnContentClick = false;
                popup.content.replaceWith(resp);
                popup.updateItemHTML();
                HandleItemFormSubmit();
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
}
```

However, despite setting `closeOnContentClick` to false at two different points, the popup immediately closes when content is clicked after the content was replaced (it does work the first time).

The content in the popup has a single root element by the way.

I hope the author or someone else can help out here, I have no idea what is wrong here.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I've found another solution:

```
$('html').on('submit', '#UR_FORM', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {
            var magnificPopup = $.magnificPopup.instance;
            magnificPopup.items[0].type = "inline";
            magnificPopup.items[0].src = response;
            magnificPopup.updateItemHTML();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `HandleItemFormSubmit` for the `popup` object:

```
HandleItemFormSubmit.call(popup);
```

Otherwise when you call it the way you do, `HandleItemFormSubmit();`, the `this` will be set to `window` and this will not work as expected.

#### Update

Use this in the *else* clause:

```
if (resp == 'OK')
{
    popup.close();  
}
else
{
    // Show HTML from response (with errors)
    popup.closeOnContentClick = false;
    popup.content.replaceWith(resp);
    popup.updateItemHTML();
    HandleItemFormSubmit.call(popup);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shimon. In the meanwhile, I've discovered that I had closeOnContentClick: false inside the callbacks list, so I moved that up to the correct place, as an option. That didn't help though. Only when I add closeOnBgClick: false it works. But then "this" won't work after the 2nd submit, so your suggestion is still needed.  Could you point out where I should use it...?